# Datastage: "connector could not find a column in the input schema" error while using oracle connector stage

Tags: datastage

When only some columns specified in the table are included in the table definition in the Oracle Connector stage, I am getting the error " The connector could not find a column in the input schema to match parameter ". Please let me know if it is necessary to include all the columns in the meta data on the oracle connector stage.

Answer (score 1):

try enabling the run time column propagation (RCP) for the project from Datastage administrator client.
It will ensure that only columns that are needed will pass smoothly from one stage to another.